# django multi-database switch login problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am a newbie to django, I am currently trying to make a project, the content is two beverage store apps, and then you must choose which database to use when logging in to the interface, and the database structure of these two beverage stores All the same, I don’t know if I should use router to do this? Or how should I deal with this problem, I hope someone can help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complex your condition is for connecting to a specific db you can get away with explicitly saying which db to connect or you'll need a db router. Either way, you first need to define your db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'database1': {
        'NAME': 'database1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_database1_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret'
    },
    'database2': {
        'NAME': 'database2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_database2_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    }
}
```

If you opt with explicitly choosing your db, you can do it like so:

```
Model.objects.using('database2').all()
```

and for save:

```
model_instance.save(using='database2')
```

For the db router, it's much more involved which is explained in detail here [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers). Whichever you choose you need to be careful with this because your data might end up all over the place. If you can simplify your app to use one db, it would be best as usually the benefits of using multi-db doesn't outweight the headaches it entails.